# Change "materialize" css framework to use "outlined" material-style form inputs

Tags: material-design, materialize

My goal is to create an input like [the one described as being 'outline variant' in these Material docs](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/text-field?type=outlined).

How do I configure and/or what CSS should I add to [materialize CSS forms](https://www.um.es/docencia/barzana/materializecss/forms.html) to use the 'outline' variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a few issues/requests for this outline variant, but the Materialize folks have indicated that it wasn't part of the spec at the time and have subsequently closed the issues.

I dug through some of the Material samples versus styling on the Materialize framework and noticed that they are handling things slightly different as far as padding, borders/shadows etc.

Achieving this outline variant as the default treatment is going to require some slightly destructive style updates that should probably be handled via the preprocessed files, but [here is an example](https://codepen.io/allusis/pen/pozgWeK) of some quick and dirty overrides

Note the addon class "input-outlined" in the markup:

```
<div class="col input-field input-outlined s6">
  <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The codepen link has scss, to convert it into css: https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, they're related but not the same project and do not use the same CSS files. I was using a CDN link for Materialize for a little while and none of the Material.io classes were taking effect.

Then I switched over to using the suggested Material.io CDN links, found here: https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/

Once I did that, I could use the HTML markup and class names that became visible on the [page you provided](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/text-field?type=filled) after I clicked the "Web" tab.

It works. [Here is a Codepen showing both styles of text inputs in action (this Codepen is using the Material.io CDN links in the settings).](https://codepen.io/lirum/pen/XvxWWB)

The main difference between filled and outlined is that filled looks to be the default. I'm inferring that the Material.io design system has you repeat the classname and append a modifier if you wish to deviate from the default.

For instance, in the linked codepen, notice that the filled (default) text field is inside `<div class="mdc-text-field">` while the outlined text field is inside `<div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined"></div>`.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the text fields don't "shift" the label as they should. Material.io doesn't have friendly class names, so I think that's pretty much out. I was hoping that materialize would provide the other variant.